# PHP replace GET-value of a variable

Tags: php, variables, replace, get

I have a URL as a string in `$url`.

I want to replace a specific parameter (if it exists) in the URL.

For example

```
$url = "http://www.xxx.xxx?data=1234324&id=abc&user=walter";
```

I'd like check if `id` exists and if it does, I want to replace the value of that `id` to a specific value. But the value of the `id` isn't always the same and it's not always in the same place.

Comment: [parse_url](https://php.net/parse_url) to get the query string ("get" string), [parse_str](https://php.net/parse_str) to parse it to an array. Check if the value [isset](https://php.net/isset) and change it then [http_build_query](https://php.net/http_build_query) to change the array back into a query string and then append it after the `?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract your query with PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
$b = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

From here you can use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get an associative array:

```
parse_str($b, $arr);
```

Now you can access the parameters

```
$arr['data'];
$arr['id'];
$arr['user'];
```

If you want to check if the `id` parameter exists you can use

```
if (isset($arr['id'])) {
//Do something
}
```

Comment: and can you explain how i get the $url with the replaced id? and how i replace the array id? :D sorry im new in arrays ( and PHP ;) for example i want to replace the value of the id from "abc" to "xyz"